# Functions acting strange when run as thread in Kivy/Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, kivy, python-multithreading

I am building an app that, when the user hits a 'run' button, generates a table of buttons.

Because this process takes a while, I want to add a popup or progress bar to alert the user that the function is running and not frozen. To do this I decided to create a popup and call my function using threading so that the screen will be updated when the function starts (as opposed to once it is done).

```
mythread = threading.Thread(target=run_function)
mythread.start()
```

The trouble is that when I call my function from the above code it works very strangely: the columns of my table are the wrong width, some of my buttons are arbitrarily empty, and others have the wrong fill color. To fix this, all I need to do is to remove the threading operation and simply call run_function()

Any idea why this is happening?

I am new to Python, so it is likely some dumb mistake, but I have no idea. What is different between a process running as a thread and its default operation?

Comment: Kivy may not be thread-safe. See e.g., https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2548

Comment: Thankyou for alerting me to this point @boardrider. I am new to developing in Kivy/Python, would you be able to suggest a simple way to bring up a poup without threading? Perhaps I could schedule an event to happen after .1 seconds to create a popup saying 'running' and then close that popup at the end of my function. If this is a valid idea, how might I do it?

Comment: Graphics-modifying operations must run in the main thread. You can open the popup there then put your long-running operation in a different thread, that should work fine.

Comment: The documentation has an example: http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.popup.html

Comment: @inclement, this is what I was trying to do, but my long running operation is supposed to update the graphics when complete (the long process is that of building a gridlayout of buttons in a scroll view). Should i build all these processes in my thread and then when the thread finishes use some sort of event in the main thread to trigger adding the new scrollview to the main view?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't worked with Kivy.

Not every framework works well with multithreading.

But most of the GUI frameworks have an [event loop](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#main-loop) which is responsible for managing user events (mouse clicks, keyboard) and queued drawing operations (widgets).

In your case if don't want the UI to be freezed, you should regularly give control to your framework's event loop.

I guess [`kivy.base.EventLoopBase.dispatch_input`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.base.html#kivy.base.EventLoopBase.dispatch_input) is what you need to call to show an added widget or to handle user events.